# Filter plugin for specific platform in phonegap/cordova

Tags: phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

is there any way to filter a plugin for a specific platform in PGB?

I want a plugin to be for iOS but not for Android. Both apps with the same code.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You use a plugin to detect which OS is running and then filter things from there.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#device.platform

Comment: Yes, what you say is the way I ended do it. But I meant if there were some kind of tag you can write in the config.xml, so you can filter plugin by platform. Thanks anyway.